# what's the most common method to distribute two linux kernel modules of different versions in only one rpm?

Tags: module, kernel, rpm

Our software has a centos 6.2 OS for users, which has two kernels installed(xen-based and orignal). So some rpms with kernel modules should both support these kernels.  What's the most commonly used solution to include two linux kernel modules of different versions in only one rpm?

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is two different binary packages,
each targeted at a a different (xen-based and original) kernel.

While it is probably feasible to package 2 kernel modules
in a single package -- particularly if both kernels are installed
everywhere --, the maintenance will drive you batty. Separate
packages is far easier to maintain, the redundant work is minuscule
compared to the cost of rebuilding/redistributing two binary
kernel module packages every time either kernel changes.